# How to migrate office 365 mailbox from one account to another 0ffice 365 mailbox using Graph API or EWS?

Tags: outlook, office365

I trying to find API migrating mailbox data from one account to another account in office 365. Graph API doesn't have the API listed for migration. It does have a APIs for moving folders.

[EWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/ews-managed-api-reference-for-exchange) does not have a reference for migration as well. Where can I find the migration APIs for email.

Answer (score 0):

EWS and MAPI are the only Exchange API's currently that will allow you to copy (or export/import) data between mailboxes. The Graph API can move data within a Mailbox but not between two mailboxes and it has limited export ability to Mime only and no import from Mime. I would start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/exporting-and-importing-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange but keep in mind that EWS will be going away at some point in the future https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/retirement-of-exchange-web-services-in-exchange-online/ba-p/3924440 so currently there isn't a future proof solution for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready-made tool for copying one account's data into another. If you have both accounts configured in Outlook you may create a VBA script for copying all the data from one account into another on the client side and then syncing with the server.

Graph API and EWS are designed for dealing with specific accounts, but not copying data from one account into another.